# EAGLE - Error when saving Library

Tags: eaglecad, cad

After I've installed EAGLE on new OS I've moved all EAGLE files from my backup to main EAGLE directory inside programs folder to recover all my lib/files. All works good but when I save changes on a library appear this message:

[image]

Library is saved correctly, but this message after each save is annoying. Someone have idea why I've this error? OS is Win10 Pro, EAGLE version is 6.5.0.

Comment: I've never seen a message with a black bar like that.  Something must be really messed up on your system.

Comment: Did you but that black bar there? To prevent us from knowing "C:\Program Files (x86)\EAGLE-x.x.x\My Library" (x.x.x being the version) you are using?

Comment: Library is a custom library, I've added black bar just to make this question more general. Like C:/Program Files/Eagle/lib/xxxxx.lbr since this error happen on all libraries I save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 (and several earlier versions) will not allow user programs to write in the Program Files(X86) or other Program Files directories.

You could move your whole Eagle directory tree to the root of C: (C:\Eagle...), or just move the Library directory tree to someplace where user programs can write.